# How to make bootstrap radio buttons (aspx)

Tags: html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a sort of profile page. I want the user to be able to select from 3 themes (it will just change the color of the pages on the site). However I don't know how to make that when the radio buttons are clicked.
Here's my code:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="panel-body">
  <div class="container">
     <form>
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="optradio">Blue
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="optradio">Red                  
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio disabled">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="optradio">Wood
            </label>
        </div>
      </form>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Question is: how do I make the radio buttons actually do something?
EDIT: My bad, I want to use actual radio buttons not buttons. I have erased the code above and replaced it.

Comment: you want the background color to change on click of radio buttons right?
example: 1st for red, 2nd for blue, 3rd for green?

Comment: after a radio button click, you will likely need an ajax call if you are not using a form with a submit button **and** are persisting theme's per user. Then it's a matter of using js to change your classes.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function red() {
    document.getElementById("he").style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
        function blue() {
    document.getElementById("he").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
        function green() {
    document.getElementById("he").style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
```

```html
<body id="he">
  <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="container">
       <form>
         <div class="radio" >
           <label>
            <input type="radio" name="optradio" onclick="blue();">Blue</label>
         </div>
         <div class="radio">
           <label>
            <input type="radio" name="optradio" onclick="red();">Red</label>
         </div>
         <div class="radio">
         <label>
           <input type="radio" name="optradio" onclick="green();">Green</label>
         </div>
         </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

This is what you are looking for right??

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but it didn't change the color of the background. Is there anything else I should be doing?

Comment: I am able to see the color change at [Tutorialpoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/try_bootstrap_online.php) play ground, but when I try to see it on JSFiddle, it's not happening. Let me see which imports I am missing.

Comment: [JSFiddle Solution](https://jsfiddle.net/dm651kou/1/) as well. All you need to make sure is about adding the CDN

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work, although I added the imports. Also, what's CDN and how do I add it?

Comment: did you give `id="he"` to the `<body>` i.e. `<body id="he">` ?

Comment: I did now. That worked, thanks! Do you know how to change the background color of all of the pages in the project? That was the initial plan. I wasn't able to find anything about that anywhere.

Comment: By all the pages you mean, set once and it should be universal to all other sub-pages right? 
Example if I have 4 pages, I set 1 to green all others should be green and if set to red all others should be red, right?

Comment: Yeah something like that.